# What are the chances of seeing a photo 2 days in a row?

Tags: probability, proportion

I've installed a photo slideshow on a small TV in our kitchen, which displays a randomly chosen family picture amongst 3'700, once every 20 seconds.

My wife frequently observes "but I saw that one yesterday", when one every 20 seconds seems to imply that she should only see the same photo once every 20-odd (3'700 * 20 / 3600) hours.

Now, of course, she looks at more than one per day so the odds diminish radically, but how?

If I have X photos and I look at Y photos every day, what are the chances that I see the **same** photo two days running?

Alternatively a formula would be nice, so that I could figure out that watching N photos a day, my collection must be >M so that there is less than 50% chance I see the **same** photo 2 days running.

Comment: Do you mean that you see the same photo on *both* day 1 and day 2? Or that you see it more than once in the span of two days? Those are different. Seeing the same photo twice in the same day, but not at all the next day still satisfies the latter criterion, but not the former.

Comment: @Bridgeburners I see photo X on Monday and then I see photo X again on Tuesday, having looked at Y random photos on Monday and again Y random photos on Tuesday.